# Get the_content with ajax

Tags: ajax, the-content

I'm using WordPress (WP) as the backend for an app that delivers content on a map.

I've been trying for a couple of days to get my head around AJAx in WP and have found a good [tutorial](http://micahwood.me/doing-ajax-in-wordpress/) I'm trying to follow.

I've adapted it for use in the theme, however how do I get it to 'GET' the_content?

The parts that are relevant:

```
function the_content( $content ) {

global $post;

if( is_single() && 'post' == $post->post_type ) { //I'll want post from a specific category, not just single posts.

$content .= '<button class="ajax-yall" data-postid="'. $post->ID .'">'.     __('Click me!', 'ajax-yall') .'</button>'; //here I want it to get the post content of posts in a particular category
}
return $content;
}
```

and

```
$.get(
        ajaxYall.ajaxurl,
        {
            action  : ajaxYall.action,
            nonce   : ajaxYall.nonce,
            postID  : $el.attr('data-postid')
        },
```

I've had various attempts at this, but my knowledge on the subject isn't sufficient.

Comment: `the_content()` is a WordPress core function. If you try to create a function called `the_content()` in the WordPress environment, it should throw a fatal error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but I think you have not read a good tutorial. If you are new to Wordpress AJAX, I recomend you reading [AJAX in WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and examples plus [all the examples you can find in this site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22ajax%20api%22).